# Blank screen when using --prod and --release to build Ionic 3 Angular 4 app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I have seen tons of people having problem similar to mine, but none of the solutions I have seen there could help me, so I am not duplicating already asked questions.

I have this environment:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 5.0.12
Node       : v7.0.0
npm        : 5.3.0
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

And I have these plugins:

```
com.googlemaps.ios 2.5.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.0 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.2 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 2.0.4 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-swift-support 3.1.1 "SwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 0.7.14 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 7.0.1 "BarcodeScanner"
```

When I check with:
**% sudo ionic doctor check**

> ✔ Detecting issues: 16 / 16 complete - done! 
>   [OK] Detected 0 issues.
>   Aww yeah!

When I run the app using this command it works perfectly, I see the blank screen but after few seconds it goes to the Login Page I have:

```
% sudo ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

But, if I try to build the production/release version I see a blank screen right after hiding the Splash Screen with the spinner:

```
% sudo ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

I wonder if would be something related to White List Plugin and permissions, would that be? But what?

As you can see I am using Crosswalk, would be something related to it?

What is the **real** difference between those two commands? What could I do to find out what is really happening when I use **--prod** and **--release**?

Comment: Since you are building for android, did you try connecting to your desktop Chrome browser? If so any messages in the console?

Comment: Everything works on Chrome, nothing unusual on console. It's something on this project. I just created a starter project and it is running Ok on android with the --prod argument.

Comment: I am not talking about Chrome using `ionic serve`. I am talking about your prod build on your phone: when you connect your phone to your desktop, you can use Chrome (desktop) to debug your android view.

Comment: I know, you mean chrome://inspect/#devices, but nothing is shown on console or on Augury tab, nothing. But thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3):

What was causing this huge problem is that I had in my **tsconfig.json**:

```
"target": "es6"
```

Because I was told to set to 6 to use async and await, but I can let it as this:

```
"target": "es5"
```

And use **Typescript 2.7.1** - I spent 5 days struggling on this problem to find out that this target was causing this annoying blank screen.

I hope may this can help others.